# material-ui-next's component Modal is not getting transpiled to ES5 by Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, material-ui

Modal, one of the material-ui-next components, is not getting transpiled to ES5-compitable code by Babel.

My .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-1", "stage-2", "stage-3"]
}
```

My webpack-config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, '../main/webapp/resources/js');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/App');

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

var config = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', APP_DIR + '/index.jsx'],
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"development"',
        })
    ],
    module : {
        rules : [
            {
                test : /\.jsx?/,
                include : APP_DIR,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader : 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

Piece of outcome code: [output code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiUXW.png).

[material-ui-next's Modal on github](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/packages/material-ui/src/Modal/Modal.js)

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the error that is being reported? Showing us the red squiggly line isn't quite enough info to figure out what the issue is :)

Comment: It says that "t is not defined". The problem appears when I use Drawer component with "variant" property set to "temporary". When I'm trying to open it, the following error occurs.

Comment: Material-ui-next's temporary Drawer uses Modal component under the hood (it's where the error occurs). Here it is shown how it works https://material-ui-next.com/demos/drawers/#responsive-drawer

Answer (score 0):

It was an import issue. I've changed this:

```
import Drawer from "material-ui/es/Drawer/Drawer";
```

To this:

`import {Drawer} from "material-ui";`

And now it works fine.